# Change GUI/Menu's language to Chromium on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, chromium, language-support

I'd like to change chromium language from English to Italian on an Ubuntu 12.04 based on English locale. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

After trying many solutions that did not work for me, here's something that just worked fine (not on Ubuntu but Linux Mint).

```
 sudo apt-get install chromium-browser-l10n
```

Answer (score 0):

well for only one application means not possible but you can do it with placing a new environment variable.

I mean open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-it
export LANG=it_IT.UTF-8
chromium
```

this is to launch chromium from terminal and it will be in Italian. when you close the terminal the session of Italian language will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, when you say chromium, it means chromium browser.

Here are the steps for anyone else interested.

1. Install language pack.
   $ sudo apt-get install language-pack-it
2. Find the "startup script" of chromium-browser.
   $ vim `which chromium-browser`
3. Add the following line in "startup script".
   $ export LANG=it_IT.UTF-8